# Cannot update identity column 'Unique ID', Entity Framework Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to update my entity using Entity Framework 4.1 code First approach like this(In my Repository Class):

```
internal void SaveAccount(Account account) {

            context.Entry(account).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

but I am getting an error which is:

```
Cannot update identity column 'Unique ID'.
```

I am not updating Unique ID Column. How can I avoid this error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added this attribute to my Model property and error gone:

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

Answer (score 1):

If the property is the primary key, the following attribute should be added instead:

```
[Key]
```